# Sort php array on one column and output to list

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have created an array that is populated from a wordpress loop:-

```
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>

        $alisting []["questions"] = $questions; 
        $alisting []["id"] = $post->ID; 
        $alisting []["title"] = $post->post_title; 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [questions] => 22 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1016 ) [2] => Array ( [title] => Cash Commons ) [3] => Array ( [questions] => 15 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 811 ) [5] => Array ( [title] => The Poker Echo ) [6] => Array ( [questions] => 34 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 437 ) [8] => Array ( [title] => VideoWTF.com ) [9] => Array ( [questions] => 34 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 295 )
```

I need to sort this array by Questions in descending order and echo it out to a list so that I will have:-

```
ID       | Title           |  Question

1023       Cash Commons       43
987        Videowtf           34
```

etc

Can someone please help with very clear instructions please.

Thanks in advance of your help.

Cheers

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the function `uasort()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php - and create a call back function to sort.

```
function sort_callback($a, $b){
    if ($a['Question'] == $b['Question']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Question'] < $b['Question']) ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($alisting,'sort_callback');
```

Comment: Thanks Mauris - doesn't seem to have worked. I wish it wasn't this hard. Here's the output using this:-

$length = count($alisting);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo $alisting[$i]['questions'].'<br>';
}


23


15


34


34


31


8

Comment: hi Jonathan, i noticed that your key is 'questions', not 'Question'. you might want to check that...

Comment: yep - I changed that function sort_callback($a, $b){
    if ($a['questions'] == $b['questions']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['questions'] < $b['questions']) ? 1 : -1;
}

Comment: Hi there i noticed it's because you are using $i for the index. the index are not changed, the order are. you might want to use var_dump to see it, or use a foreach.

Comment: This is driving me mad  - why is it so hard - can someone please help with a code example that can work  - I really need this

Comment: excellent the var_dump shows that the sort has worked - thank you so much - how do I loop through the array and echo it out to a list and preserve the sort order?

Comment: it seems that the vardump shows that the order is correct but it lists all the question rows in descending order then all the title fields and then the ID's - I really need to output all elements together but in descending order  of the questions element
  - any ideas anyone?

Comment: Hi there sorry I was out for the day. You will need to use a `foreach` instead of `for` in order to loop through the array in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

use array_multisort

Comment: please elaborate answer and give examples.

Comment: @Mark i know. wnoveno should at least provide a better answer.